# OpenSSL library stress tolerance

Tags: c++, multithreading, ssl, openssl

My coworkers and I have a good feeling that OpenSSL more or less needs to get pitched from our application but I want some opinions on whether it really is this bad or whether there are issues in our use of this library that could be causing us trouble.

The setting:  A multi-threaded C++ application that maintains a persistent SSL connection for each user.

At 500 users it has worked fine.  I'm trying to increase the limit to 1000 and around 960 had a segfault in `SSL_read`.  This read is the first I/O operation for this particular connection.  I had to increase the file limit in `ulimit` from 1024 to 4096 to get up this high.  So my questions are:

1)  Is it possible the library needs to be configured to know to accept this many connections?

2)  Is it a threading issue that may be solved with light use of mutexes?  I can't afford to turn the entire SSL_read into a critical strip though.

3)  Just a bad buggy library and needs to be thrown out?

Comment: OpenSSL works fine in many applications. What version are you using?

Comment: Looks like `OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010`

Comment: How is multithreading involved?

Comment: openssl is being used in countless applications, of which many surely have higher requirements than yours, and all seem to run very stable. Even if you found a bug (and I doubt you did), what would you want to use as an alternative?

Comment: @Brady - One thread per connection.  So could be concurrent access of the read/write.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - Coworker found "some other library" which I'm not excited to implement until I know I'm using openssl correctly...  hence my post here.

Comment: @djechlin: To judge if you use openssl correctly, we would need to know how you use it. A selfcontaining compilable testcase would be ideal for it.

Comment: Can we see the segfault stack trace?

Comment: I only have the stack trace down to openssl.so.  I could try compiling the library with `-g` from scratch to see what happens inside of it?
As for small sample code I'm not sure how easily I can produce that.  It's a segfault that only happened when I had a lot of stuff flying over the connections - it runs perfectly @ 500 users and failed @ 1000.

Comment: Have you read the OpenSSL documentation page on threading and have you provided OpenSSL with callbacks to your locking functions?  http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/threads.html

Comment: @indiv - Yes.  I just reviewed the code I have doing that and it looks perfect.

Comment: OpenSSL ships as part of the Apache HTTP server, OpenLDAP, and dozens of other standard software packages. It is one of the most widely used SSL libraries on the planet. I suggest your difficulties are more local ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, 1 thread per connection doesnt seem like an efficient usage of threads.

I would suggest a thread pool and use worker threads to handle received packets. The received packets could be enqueued in a queue and the worker threads would process packets from the queue. The openSsl connections could be stored in a container common to all threads. Care will have to be taken to handle the packets in order. And yes, synchronization (mutex) will be needed.

Comment: Well, let's see if that's possible in my application - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018776/is-it-possible-to-thread-pool-imap-connections