# Is it possible to thread pool IMAP connections?

Tags: ssl, imap, threadpool

From what I understand IMAP requires a connection per each user.  I'm writing an IMAP client (currently just gmail) that supports many (100s, 1000s maybe 10000s+) users at a time.  Obviously cutting down the number of open connections would be great.  I'm wondering if it's possible to use thread pooling on my side to connect to gmail via IMAP or if that simply isn't supported by the IMAP protocol.

Comment: I wouldnt think the IMAP protocol would be affected by those sorts of implementation details. Even though you use a relatively small thread pool (less number of threads than connections) the state of the TCP connections will not be affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMAP typically uses SSL over TCP/IP. And a TCP/IP connection will need to be maintained per IMAP client connection, meaning that there will be many simultaneous open connections.

These multiple simultaneous connections can easily be maintained in a non-threaded (single thread) implementation without affecting the state of the TCP connections. You'll have to have some sort of a flow concept per IMAP TCP/IP connection, and store all of the flows in a container (a c++ STL map for instance) using the TCP/IP five-tuple (or socketFd) as a key. For each data packet received, lookup the flow and handle the packet accordingly. There is nothing about this approach that will affect the TCP nor IMAP connections.

Considering that this will work in a single-thread environment, adding a thread pool will only increase the throughput of the application, since you can handle data packets for several flows simultaneously (assuming its a multi-core CPU) You will just need to make sure that 2 threads dont handle data packets for the same flow at the same time, which could cause the packets to be handled out of order. An approach could be to have a group of flows per thread, maybe using IP pools or something similar.

Comment: So you're saying - must have a TCP/IP connection per IMAP client connection.  However can use pooling to avoid having one thread per connection.

Comment: @djechlin, exactly, but just be careful to avoid processing the same flow in multiple threads at the same time, like I mentioned. I work in telecom on a product that does exactly this.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  I can afford threads currently - going to run out of connections/machine sooner I think.  But this might be worth getting our memory footprint hence costs down a little more marginally going forward.